# Rails - Displaying a substring of each item in mapped array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, dictionary, ruby-on-rails-4, substring

I have this code in my view.

```
<%= matchset.games.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
```

It is taking an array of game_ids and displaying the name of each one. However, I only want to display the last seven characters of each game name, not the entire name.

Is there a way to take a substring of the name when it is part of an array being mapped from id to name like this?

Comment: Can't you just `#collect` the name substrings?

Comment: I'm pretty new to rails so I'm not sure how that would work. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, there's nothing taking "an array of game_ids", you're working with games.

After the `map` you end up with a collection of names, which I assume are strings, e.g.,

```
["Bartholemew", "Jimmy", "Johnathon"]
```

There are two trivial ways to do what you want.

```
matchset.games.collect { |g| g.name[0..6] }.join(", ")
```

Or:

```
matchset.games.collect(&:name).collect { |n| n[0..6] }.join(", ")
```

The first only loops once, the second twice. If it's a short collection, it probably doesn't matter a whole lot. In the first it takes a little longer to comprehend what's happening because you have to read the code in order to understand you're ending up with names.

It might make more sense to put this operation in a decorator so the view layer sees only:

```
<%= matchset.truncated_names %>
```

or something similar.

Depending on where things are happening you might also consider using `pluck` but whether or not that makes sense depends on how else you're using `games` on the page, if you even are.